# Save Json object to Couchdb

Tags: ruby, json, couchdb

I would like to write a ruby script that will save the Json object stored in a file to Couchdb.

A code snippet to exmplain this would be very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is all you want: [Getting started with Ruby](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script like this which did the trick for me!

require 'json'
require 'rest_client'
require 'couchrest'
require 'pp'

```
json = File.read('file.json')
doc = JSON.parse(json)
CouchRest.post('http://localhost:5984/db/',doc)

pp doc
```